# I'd like to change certain directories ( like /icons/) from 403 forbidden to 404 not found

Tags: apache2

I got security check and I have to fix the problems.

I operate the homepage via virtual machine (Ubuntu 16.04.3) by apache2 (Apache 2.4.18).

The security check said that accessing `~/icons/`, `~/icons/small/`, `~/javascript/` get respond status code 403 (Forbidden) and I have to change them to status code 404 (Not Found) for security.

So, I add in `.htaccess` file

```
RedirectMatch 404 /icons/
RedirectMatch 404 /icons/small/ 
RedirectMatch 404 /javascript/
```

but it didn't work...

Acutally when I add

```
RedirectMatch 404 /intro/
```

then it works in `~/intro/`

So, I think the `/icons/` and `/javascript/` are something different.

Does anybody know why and how to deal with it?

`/icons/` is aliased to `/usr/share/apache2/icons/` and I change to

```
RedirectMatch 404 /usr/share/apache2/icons/
```

but it also doesn't work....

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is essentially cover your ass security. If you use any resources from `/icons/` it will be fairly obvious that it is there, and a 404 will not change that. A 403 indicates that the server is correctly configured.

If you really want to do this, `RedirectMatch` is the way to go.

```
RedirectMatch 404 ^/icons/$
```

will return 404 for `example.com/icons/`, but not `example.com/icons/foo.png`.

```
RedirectMatch 404 ^/icons/.*$
```

will return for `example.com/icons/foo.png` (and any other file in icons) as well.

Note that if the resources in `/icons/` are referenced directly in the output to the browser, this does not improve security in any way, as it's trivially evident that `/icons` exists. If they are not referenced in the output, but merely used as input for scripts, you should consider moving them out of webroot.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
I also think this is useless security check...

Anyway, your solution doesn't work. I don't know but I think ~/icons/ and ~/javascript/ are something special.

Comment: Is the URL example.com/~/icons?

Comment: No, the url is example.com/icons/ , example.com/icons/small/, example.com/javascript/  
   
I'm sorry for late reply. I've got a cold....